# PHP function output sent as variable across GET

Tags: php

This code with a couple of functions to modify a date works:

```
<?php

function date_up($input_date){
  echo date("Y-m-d",strtotime('+1 day',strtotime($input_date)));
}

function date_up_friday($input_date){
  echo date("Y-m-d",strtotime('+3 day',strtotime($input_date)));
}

function date_down($input_date){
  return date("Y-m-d",strtotime('-1 day',strtotime($input_date)));
}

function date_down_monday($input_date){
  echo date("Y-m-d",strtotime('-3 day',strtotime($input_date)));
}

echo 'Input date: ';echo $date='2017-09-25';
echo '<BR><BR>';
echo 'Down 1: ';
echo date_down($date);
echo '<BR>';
echo 'Down 3: ';date_down_monday($date);
echo '<BR>';
echo 'Up 1: ';date_up($date);
echo '<BR>';
echo 'Up 3: ';date_up_friday($date);

?>
```

I am trying to send the output from the function to another page when the hyperlink.  New code shown below.  But no date is sent in the hyperlink.  I don't understand this and I apologise if their is a simple explanation.  I am new to working with PHP.

Many thanks in advance !

```
echo 'Input date: ';echo $date='2017-09-25';
echo '<BR><BR>';
echo '<a href="Dev/Update_date_shortfall.php?date="';
echo date_down($date);
echo '">Down 1: </a>';
echo date_down($date);
echo '<BR>';
echo 'Down 3: ';date_down_monday($date);
echo '<BR>';
echo 'Up 1: ';date_up($date);
echo '<BR>';
echo 'Up 3: ';date_up_friday($date);
```

Comment: How do you access this `?date=` in another page?

Comment: I think you missed the date in href

Comment: You have a closing " in the href, look at line 3 date=" remove the quote. You should also do this all inline, view @milan-chheda answer for a better approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to send it like this:

```
echo '<a href="Dev/Update_date_shortfall.php?date=' . date_down($date) . '">Down 1: </a>';
```

And in `Update_date_shortfall.php`, you need to

```
echo $_GET['date'];
```

Comment: You have a typo, this will not work:

    href="Dev/Update_date_shortfall.php?date=" <---'

You have a closing "

Comment: @viion - Thanks. Good observation.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I have updated my code with .date_down($date). in the middle of the <a> tag but this has not solved my PHP page.

on the update_date_shortfall.php page it does select the date using $_GET I will update my original answer to give more information on this.  Do you have any ideas why the result from date_down() function is not passed to the <a> hyperlink ? Even though it is echoed on the page.

Comment: Ah I didn't see the typo comment, just loaded after my response.  I shall test it without they typo...

Comment: @JCBuckingham - In your functions, instead of `echo`, you should have `return`

Comment: Thanks Milan Chheda, I will update the other functions to return. date_down() function was set to return but the others were left to echo, good spot! thanks again

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
echo '<a href="Dev/Update_date_shortfall.php?date=' . date_down($date) . '">Down 1: </a>';
```

working demo : https://ideone.com/bZNwMr

Comment: Can you explain how is this different from my answer?